# Problemas para enviar parámetros STRING en el execute() de las consultas PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo, parametros

Estoy intentando enviar diferentes parámetros en una consulta `SQL` con `PDO` y los parámetros de valor entero si se ejecutan correctamente

```
$bindParams_Array = [] ;
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ROL WHERE id= ?';
array_push($bindParams_Array,1);
$statement = $conexion->pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($bindParams_Array)
```

Con lo anterior no tengo ningún problema, el problema se presenta a continuación

**Al intentar hacer la consulta con parámetros `string` y mas de un valor tengo problemas**

```
$bindParams_Array = [] ;
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ROL WHERE nombre LIKE CONCAT("?","%")';
array_push($bindParams_Array,"A");
$statement = $conexion->pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($bindParams_Array)
```

**La consulta se executa, pero es como si no procesara los datos ya que no devuelve nada**

> array(0) { }

Revise la consulta para ver si tenia algún error y le quite los parámetros y funciona correctamente `$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ROL WHERE nombre LIKE CONCAT("A","%")';`

Ya también probé lo siguiente:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ROL WHERE nombre LIKE CONCAT(":nombre","%")';
$statement->execute(array('nombre' => "A");
```

Sin tener un resultado satisfactorio.

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente, los marcadores de posición (`?`) no se ponen nunca entre comillas, tampoco los marcadores de `:nombre`.

De todos modos, el principal problema en tu código es que estás complicando la vida, pues **no necesitas usar `CONCAT` aquí, ni tampoco necesitas usar `array_push`**.

Si escribes tu código así funcionará igual, y estará más optimizado:

### Con marcadores de posición (`?`)

```
$bindParams_Array = array("%A");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ROL WHERE nombre LIKE ?";
$statement = $conexion->pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($bindParams_Array)
```

### Con marcadores de `:nombre`

```
$bindParams_Array = array(":mParams"=>"%A");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ROL WHERE nombre LIKE :mParams";
$statement = $conexion->pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($bindParams_Array)
```

Si observas bien en ambos casos, **los marcadores `%` del `LIKE` van en la cadena que pasas como parámetro, no en la consulta preparada**, en la cual sólo debes poner un marcador como haces con cualquier consulta, el cual sirve para indicar al manejador que ahí va un dato que será pasado en el `execute`. Quizá ha sido ese concepto errado el que te ha conducido a usar `CONCAT`, a usar `array_push` y a complicarte la vida sin necesidad.

Del mismo modo, si en vez de querer buscar un `LIKE '%A'` necesitaras buscar un `LIKE '%A%'` tienes que indicarlo en el mismo dato, no en la consulta, declarando el array así: `$bindParams_Array = array("%A%");` La consulta preparada, en este caso sería la misma: `SELECT * FROM ROL WHERE nombre LIKE ?`. Como ves, no se usa `CONCAT` para nada, y es que, no lo podría probar ahora, pero usar `CONCAT` podría suponer incluso un riesgo, porque podrías estar permitiendo que se **concatene** código malicioso en la consulta SQL.

Para más detalles puedes consultar el [apartado relativo a `LIKE`](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#like) en la guía sobre PDO de PHPDelusions. Si lees esta guía completa te ayudará mucho en el uso de PDO.

Comment: Tendré en cuenta la respuesta para la depuración de código, me servirá bastante lo obtenido de la respuesta.

Comment: @FernyCortez acabo de corregir algo, realmente tampoco los marcadores de `:nombre` se ponen entre comillas en las consultas preparadas (me refiero a la variable `$sql`).

Comment: Si, porque ya lo interpreta como texto, solo sería cuestión de que al valor del marcador se pusiera en comillas para ser un texto y tendré en cuenta lo del `CONCAT` según yo era más práctico para utilizar dentro del `LIKE`

Comment: No es más práctico y podría ser inseguro, @FernyCortez . Lo correcto es pasar todo el valor que quieres usar como filtro a la cadena que pasarás en el `execute`. Ese es el sentido de las consultas preparadas, por un lado, en la instrucción SQL se marca **solamente** donde van los datos y los datos en sí se pasan en el `execute`.

Comment: En cuanto tenga tiempo probaré el código

Answer (score 0):

Mi Problema era tratar de interpretar un texto desde la consulta

```
CONCAT('?',"%")
```

Cuando el texto lo determino en el array `array_push($bindParams_Array, "A")`

por lo que my `SQL` debe quedar si comillas:

```
CONCAT(?,"%")
```

Al final era error de sintaxis